# Several controllers imported in one router file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, controller, backend

Let's say there are 2 models: `User` and `Post`.

I wanted to write a function that returns all the posts written by a particular user. For that, I made a function called `readPostsByUserId`.

---

I set the function `readPostsByUserId` within the controller `posts.controller.js`.

- Question 1: Is that ok or should I set that function in the controller `users.controller.js` instead?

---

If I keep the function `readPostsByUserId` in the controller `posts.controller.js`, in the user's routes file called `users.routes.config.js`, I need to import the PostsController and do:

```js
router.get('/:id/posts', PostsController.readPostsByUserId)
```

ending up with a route `/users/:user_id/posts` which is what I need.

- Question 2: Is it ok to have a controller imported in a router file with different models? In this case, I would be importing the PostsController into the user's routes file.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking at this from a hierarchy perspective:

- `model` => `controller` => `view`
- `users` => `posts` (for all: `model`, `controller`, `view`)

You already have that hierarchy with `router.get('/:id/posts', ...)`, e.g. `users` => `posts`

Answer to Q1: Based on hierarchy the `readPostsByUserId` is better located at `users.controller.js`.

Answer to Q2: The router is simply the glue that routes different endpoints to different controller APIs, so, yes, it is ok to reference multiple controllers in the router.